# Lookup value from multiple columns that is the closest match to another column

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the closest match to the value from `lastseen` from a series of other columns when a site was visited (`d1`,`d2`,`d3`,`d4`,`d5`) in order to create a new column `nextvisit` that has the value from `d1`,`d2`,`d3`,`d4`, or `d5` that is the next largest from the value in `lastseen` (i.e., the next visit after an individual was last seen).

A reproducible example:

```
indiv lastseen d1  d2  d3  d4   d5
A     2         2   4   5   8   10
B     5         2   3   5   7    9
C     9         1   6   9  11   15
```

So the answer I'm looking for is:

```
indiv lastseen d1  d2  d3  d4   d5  nextvisit
A     2         2   4   5   8   10          4
B     5         2   3   5   7    9          7
C     9         1   6   9  11   15         11
```

As in, 4 is the next largest number within columns `d1:d5` above 2 for individual A.

I've tried using tidyr and dplyr but I can't get it to find the next largest match effectively.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`, we `gather` the columns 'd1' through 'd5' into 'long' format, grouped by 'indiv', create a difference column between the 'val' and 'last seen', `slice` the row that have the minimum positive value, `select` the columns of interest and do a join with original dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   gather(key, val, d1:d5) %>%
   group_by(indiv) %>% 
   mutate(Diff = val -lastseen, 
          Diff = replace(Diff, Diff <=0, NA)) %>% 
   slice(which.min(Diff)) %>% 
   select(indiv, val) %>% 
   right_join(df1) %>%
   select(names(df1), everything())
# A tibble: 3 x 8
# Groups:   indiv [3]
#  indiv lastseen    d1    d2    d3    d4    d5   val
#  <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 A            2     2     4     5     8    10     4
#2 B            5     2     3     5     7     9     7
#3 C            9     1     6     9    11    15    11
```

---

Another option is using `max.col` from `base R`.  Get the difference of the 'd' columns with that of 'last seen' into an object ('m1'), replace the values that are less than or equal to 0 to a very large number, use `max.col` to get the column index of each row that have the maximum value (reverse logic - changed it to negative), `cbind` with the row index and extract the value from the 'd' columns that correspond to it.

```
m1 <- df1[3:7] -df1$lastseen
m1[m1 <=0] <- 999
df1$val <- df1[3:7][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), max.col(-m1, 'first'))]
df1$val
#[1]  4  7 11
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(indiv = c("A", "B", "C"), lastseen = c(2L, 5L, 
9L), d1 = c(2L, 2L, 1L), d2 = c(4L, 3L, 6L), d3 = c(5L, 5L, 9L
), d4 = c(8L, 7L, 11L), d5 = c(10L, 9L, 15L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider `df` is your data.frame. Here´s a full R base approach

```
> ind <- (df[, -c(1,2)]- df[, 2])>0
> df$nextvisit <- apply(df[, -c(1,2)]*ind, 1, function(x) min(x[x!=0]))
> df
  indiv lastseen d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 nextvisit
1     A        2  2  4  5  8 10         4
2     B        5  2  3  5  7  9         7
3     C        9  1  6  9 11 15        11
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `base R` option

```
idx <- which(DF[-c(1, 2)] == DF$lastseen, arr.ind = TRUE)
idx[, "col"] <- idx[, "col"] + 1 # lastseen + 1 = next visit (in terms of column positions)
DF$nextvisit <- DF[-c(1, 2)][idx]
DF
#  indiv lastseen d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 nextvisit
#1     A        2  2  4  5  8 10         4
#2     B        5  2  3  5  7  9         7
#3     C        9  1  6  9 11 15        11
```

**data**

```
DF <- structure(list(indiv = c("A", "B", "C"), lastseen = c(2L, 5L, 
9L), d1 = c(2L, 2L, 1L), d2 = c(4L, 3L, 6L), d3 = c(5L, 5L, 9L
), d4 = c(8L, 7L, 11L), d5 = c(10L, 9L, 15L)), .Names = c("indiv", 
"lastseen", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = read.table(text = "
indiv lastseen d1  d2  d3  d4   d5
                A     2         2   4   5   8   10
                B     5         2   3   5   7    9
                C     9         1   6   9  11   15
                ", header=T)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(indiv, lastseen) %>%  # for each combination
  nest() %>%                     # nest data
  mutate(nextvisit = map2(lastseen, data, ~{vec = unlist(.y); min(vec[vec > .x])})) %>%  # get the minimum value higher than the corresponding lastseen value
  unnest()                       # unnest data

# # A tibble: 3 x 8
#   indiv lastseen nextvisit    d1    d2    d3    d4    d5
#   <fct>    <int>     <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 A            2         4     2     4     5     8    10
# 2 B            5         7     2     3     5     7     9
# 3 C            9        11     1     6     9    11    15
```

Comment: Good use of map2

Comment: Thanks. Was looking for a "better" function to provide, but seems that I have to `unlist`.

Answer (score 1):

another base R way:

```
df$lastvisit <- apply(df[,-1], 1, function(x) min(tail(x,5)[tail(x,5)>head(x,1)]))
```

or less readable but shorter:

```
df$lastvisit <- apply(df[,-1], 1, function(x) min(x[-1][x[-1]>x[1]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which combines `data.table` and the `Find()` function:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, nextvisit := Find(function(x) x > lastseen, .SD), .SDcols = d1:d5, by = indiv]
df1[]
```

> ```
>    indiv lastseen d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 nextvisit
> 1:     A        2  2  4  5  8 10         4
> 2:     B        5  2  3  5  7  9         7
> 3:     C        9  1  6  9 11 15        11
> ```

`Find()` applies the filter function  `function(x) x > lastseen` on the `.SD` columns from left to right in each row and returns the first element which fulfills the condition. The `.SD` columns are specified by `.SDcols = d1:d5`.

Note that the values in each row are required to be already sorted in ascending order from left to right. If not sure, .SD. can be replaced by `sort(.SD)`.

Answer (score 0):

A tidyverse solution, fully vectorized and no conversion to matrix here:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  transmute_at(vars(starts_with("d")), ~ ifelse(.x>.y, .x, Inf), .$lastseen) %>%
  invoke(pmin,.) %>%
  bind_cols(df1,nextvisit=.)

#      indiv lastseen d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 nextvisit
#    1     A        2  2  4  5  8 10         4
#    2     B        5  2  3  5  7  9         7
#    3     C        9  1  6  9 11 15        11
```